# Ajax POST - Not returning JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './checkcolors.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        url: '<?php echo $LINK;?>',
        SizeId: SelectedSizeID
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.ColorImagesNOColor').fadeIn();
        $('#LoadingImage').hide();
        data.forEach(function(id){
            $('#' + data["colorids"]).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Here is checkcolors.php code:

```
<?PHP
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $SizeId = $_POST['SizeId'];    

    if(isset($_POST['url']))
    {   
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

        $DataVariants = $xpath->query('//span[@class="ImgButWrap"]/@data-variants')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $jsonStart = strpos($DataVariants, '[');
        $jsonEnd = strrpos($DataVariants, ']');

        $collections = json_decode(substr($DataVariants, $jsonStart, $jsonEnd - $jsonStart + 1));   

        foreach ($collections as $item) {
            $ColVarId = $item->ColVarId;

            $SizeNames = [];
            foreach ($item->SizeVariants as $size) {
                $SizeNames[] = $size->SizeName;
            }

            if (in_array($SizeId, $SizeNames)) {
                echo json_encode(array('colorids' => $ColVarId));
            }


        }
    }   

?>
```

The result must give back many IDs which corresponds to ids of HTML `<div></div>` elements which i have to hide. Somehow i do not get an response from checkcolors.php correctly. There are no browser console errors.

Can you help me out resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make the array in `foreach` and after `foreach` return the _json_

Comment: Please give an example as answer to the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your json_encode is inside an if statement, nothing gets outputed if the if statement is false... and always add an error callback to check for errors for requests. Also you are creating an associative array in your php code for the json_encode... associative arrays get treated as objects when json_encoded/decoded, as such `data.forEach` is going to fail because `data` is not an array

Comment: The if statement is true. So i do not think this is the problem

Comment: I didn't say it was the cause of your problem, it's just one of the many logic problems you have. Also you should only call `echo json_encode` once as calling it multiple times will cause invalid json response

Comment: Add an error handler to your Ajax call!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
if (in_array($SizeId, $SizeNames)) {
    echo json_encode(array('colorids' => $ColVarId));
}
```

Use this:

```
if (in_array($SizeId, $SizeNames)) {
    $result[] = $ColVarId;
}
```

Before the foreach:

```
$result = array();
```

After the foreach:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now you've got an array that looks like in JS success:

```
["1", "2", "3"] ...
```

Your script should be like:

```
data.forEach(function(id){
    console.log(id); // will log: 1
});
```

Comment: Now i got other error: `Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Without source data of loaded html/xml file it is impossible to find bug. Possibly, you have broken source. I offer you to put "echo"s or "[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)"s or "[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)"s after each row of variable assignment. So you'll see where data appears distorted.